# eBay Trading API CORS issue

Tags: web-services, curl, post, cors, ebay-api

I am trying to make a `GetOrders` call on eBay Trading API, and am getting CORS error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin '' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

These are the headers :

Request URL:https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll, Request Method:OPTIONS

```
Status Code:200 OK Request Headersview source Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:x-ebay-api-siteid, x-ebay-api-dev-name, content-type, x-ebay-api-cert-name, accept, x-ebay-api-request-encoding, x-ebay-api-call-name, x-ebay-api-app-name, x-ebay-api-compatibility-level
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST Connection:keep-alive
Host:api.ebay.com Origin:<mydomain.com>
Referer:<mydomain.com> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36
```

Response Headers:

```
Allow:GET, HEAD, POST, TRACE, OPTIONS
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Date:Sun, 19 Jan 2014 18:15:10 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-EBAY-ESB-GUID:urn:uuid:UUIDDDODSDFLSDKLSDKFJKS
X-EBAY-ESB-SITEID:0
```

Does eBay need to explicitly "allow" my domain for CORS ? I have searched internet, and eBay API documentation, and there is no indication of this. If I use curl, the API call is successfully run, though the eBay trading API does not return `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In practice, all browsers enforce the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing restrictions described in the [CORS standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) which includes sending the preflight OPTIONS request like you're seeing.  The check is not mandatory, though and non-browser user agents such as curl, Android/iOS HTTP clients, etc. generally do not enforce this check.

There is no eBay developer process for allowing particular domains to make cross-domain resource requests.  The CORS support is somewhat patchy across the different APIs.  For example, the finding API call findItemsByKeywords works fine cross-domain (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143610/ebay-finding-api-call-not-working/28504254#28504254)), while other services don't allow it (see a very old but still unanswered request [here](https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/3138/jsonpcors-support-for-findhalfitems.html)).

This is not a great answer, but you can always use a backend proxy to make your calls.  In this way, your backend can make the calls with curl or the like, and you also get the benefit of being able to hide your appID, user tokens and other secrets from local inspection of your javascript.

You may also want to file a request with eBay, but some of those tickets have been languishing for some time.